# Populating a SelectList with Parent/Child Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I am trying to populate an Html.DropDownList in MVC. The problem I'm having is that I have a child table called "ODSessionTopics" that has a foreign key (ID) to the "ODSessionType" table which contain the headers for the topics. Here are my models:

```
public class ODSessionTopic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // foreign key
    public int ODSessionTypeID { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public virtual ODSessionType ODSessionType { get; set; }               
}

public class ODSessionType
{
    public int ODSessionTypeID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<ODSessionTopic> ODSessionTopics { get; set; } 
}
```

I use the following code to populate the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.ODSessionTopicID = new SelectList(db.ODSessionTopics, "ID", "Description", "ODSessionTypeID", oDSession.ODSessionTopicID);
```

Here is the OD Session Topic data:

```
    ID           Description            ODSessionTypeID
    ---------------------------------------------------
    1            Internal Marketing     1
    2            Team Development       1
    3            Department Retreat     2
    4            Community Service      2
```

Here is the OD Session Type data:

```
    ODSessionTypeID           Description
    ------------------------------------- 
    1                         Plan     
    2                         Action
```

These are my results:

```
    1 
       Internal Marketing
       Team Development
    2
       Department Retreat
       Community Services
```

Here are the results I am trying to achieve:

```
    Plans
       Internal Marketing
       Team Development
    Actions
       Department Retreat
       Community Services
```

The view code is

```
@Html.DropDownList("ODSessionTopicID", null, "-- Session Type --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Basically, it's grabbing the ODSessionTypeID foreign key in the ODSessionTopic table and grouping by that value. What I need it to do is grab the description from the ODSessionType table. Is this possible? Both the topics and the types are editable and have CRUD logic attached to them which is how I arrived to this design in the first place.

Comment: What result are your wanting? If you just want to display the 4 items un-grouped, then it should be `new SelectList(db.ODSessionTopics, "ID", "Description")` but its unclear what property of which model you trying to bind to (show how you generate the dropdown in the view. And what do you mean by _grab the description from the ODSessionType table_?

Comment: I want the dropdown to display the results from the ODSessionTopic table (shown correctly in the results picture above) and the headers (ODSessionType.Description) from the ODSessionType table. The tables are linked by the foreign key ODSessionTypeID so I want the dropdown to basically query the ODSessionType table using the ODSessionTypeID and match it with a description (ODSessionType.Description).  Here is the dropdown code:               Html.DropDownList("ODSessionTopicID", null, "-- Session Type --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Edit the question with your code. Still does not make sense. What is `oDSession.ODSessionTopicID` (neither of your models have a property named `ODSessionTopicID`) And which property are you trying to bind to?

Comment: OK, I updated my question with some more descriptions. The oDSession.ODSessionTopicID is the table and field where the user's selection is stored which works correctly. The bottom line is that I'm trying to get ODSessionType.Description to display in the dropdown instead of ODSessionType.ODSessionTypeID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linq `.Join()` and project the results to an anonymous object. Assuming `var topics = db.ODSessionTopics;` and `var types = db.ODSessionTypes;` then the query would be

```
var query = from topic in topics
            join type in types on topic.ODSessionTypeID equals type.ODSessionTypeID
            select new { Group = type.Description, ID = topic.ID, Description = topic.Description };
```

which will output

```
{ Group: "Plan", ID: 1, Description: "Internal Marketing" }
{ Group: "Plan", ID: 2, Description: "Team Development" }
{ Group: "Action", ID: 3, Description: "Department Retreat" }
{ Group: "Action", ID: 4, Description: "Community Services" }
```

and to create the `SelectList`

```
ViewBag.ODSessionTopicID = new SelectList(query, "ID", "Description", "Group", oDSession.ODSessionTopicID)
```

Side note: Recommend you use the strongly typed html helpers to generate your dropdownlist. Your `ViewBag` property should not be the same name as the property your binding to. Instead it should be (say)

```
ViewBag.TopicList = new SelectList(query, "ID", "Description", "Group", null)
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ODSessionTopicID, (SelectList)ViewBag.TopicList, "-- Session Type --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: That works! Stephen, you're a genius. Thanks so much for your help, must appreciated!

Comment: Done! Thanks again for helping out a noobie!